# 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

```
{% if movies.has_other_pages %}
 <ul class="pagination">
  {% if movies.has_previous %}
    <li class="pagination-item">
      <a href="?page={{ movies.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="pagination-item">
      <a>Previous</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for i in movies.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if movies.number == i %}
      <li class="pagination-item current-page"><a>{{i}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="pagination-item"><a href="?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I'm trying to use paginator in django but it seems like something is wrong but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i.number == 1`?

Comment: @2ps hey, I edited the code so its much more clear now! :)